# What is the british flag in skype and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: skype

Randomly, when someone sends a message, I get this:

[image]

And

[image]

These happen to be from the same person however that's not a point I'm trying to make. Ignore the name.

These are things I've noticed

- It's never come from my messages
- It's come from many people, all of which are not (to their knowledge) using a plugin that does this
- It seems random, I haven't seen a pattern
- I don't remember when it started happening but it has been for a while, it's not a recent problem
- It seems automatic (it's sent almost instantly)
- I haven't seen a message that causes it. In this case the person sent a fake word however it doesn't seem like autocorrect, I've seen it do the same thing with correctly formulated sentences.

How do I stop it, and what's causing it? My skype has no plugins installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description matches the behaviour of a Skype plugin called 'Clownfish'

Here's a similar question on the Skype forums, with a response stating that Skype provides no auto-translation: http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Auto-translation/m-p/1012422

Here's the Clownfish software page: http://clownfish-translator.com/

Maybe someone else has installed the plugin on their account on the same computer, and it has affected your Skype settings as well. Search for 'clownfish skype' images on google and see if it matches what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Click on Clownfish, and the top option should say "Disable Translation" Once you've selected that, you should be good to go.